# Angular2 NgModel ViewModel

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive to convert number to percentage for example

number / 100

but I don't want the user to see for example 5/100 = 0.05 in the model I want to see it 5

[image]

this is an example: the user sees 5.12/ but it's value to be send in backend should be changed 5.12/100

my code looks like this

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit  } from   '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[toPercentage]',
  providers: [NgModel]
})
export class ToPercentageDirective implements OnInit {


 constructor(private element: ElementRef, 
          private ngModel: NgModel) { }

 ngOnInit() {

    console.log("init");


    this.ngModel.valueChanges.subscribe(function (value){
      var percent = value / 100;
      $(this.element.nativeElement).data("newValue",percent);
      console.log(percent)
    });


 $(this.element.nativeElement).bind("customEvent", function(newVal){
     this.ngModel.update.emit(newVal);
 });
```

}

how do I achieve this ?

when it comes from backend to be multiplied by *100 and when it goes to backend to be divided by /100

Comment: I'm not sure of what you actualy want to do, but you cannot access `ngModel` programaticaly. you can however implement `CustomValueAccessor`.

Comment: I want the user to see his input, but the value to be changed

Comment: You need to use pipes, there is a built in percent pipe.

Comment: @Avi that is not something I want to achieve